# Reading a struct from a memory buffer raises a compiler error and segfault

Tags: c, pointers, casting, compiler-warnings

In the following piece of code, I attempt to store a `struct` inside a raw memory buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int a;
} Thing;

int main(void) {
  uint8_t* buffer = malloc(sizeof(Thing) * 200);

  Thing thing;
  thing.a = 80;

  memcpy(buffer, &thing, sizeof(Thing));

  Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer[0];

  return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following compiler warning:

```
warning: cast to 'Thing *' from smaller integer type
      'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
      Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer[0]
```

Also, when I try to dereference `thing_ptr` at the end:

```
printf("%d\n", thing_ptr->a);
```

I get a `segmentation fault`.

Two questions:

A. What's wrong with `Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer[0];`? Why is it raising an error?

B. What is the reason for the segfault?

Comment: `Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer[0];` -> `Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) &buffer[0];`

Comment: ... because `buffer[0]` is of type `uint8_t` so that won't make a valid pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer[0];
```

is incorrect.

The variable `buffer` is a `uint8_t *`, so `buffer[0]` is a `uint8_t`. In this case, `buffer[0]` is equivalent to `*buffer`.

There are two options:

You can take the address of `buffer[0]`:

```
Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) &buffer[0];
```

In this case, this doesn't make much sense, though it can clarify intent in some other situations.

In my opinion, the better option is to drop the `[0]`:

```
Thing* thing_ptr = (Thing*) buffer;
```

This clearly shows that you're casting the value in `buffer` from the type `uint8_t *` to a `Thing *`.

---

The `[-Wint-to-pointer-cast]` warning indicates that you're casting to a pointer from an integer type that is a different size. This type of cast usually doesn't make sense to do.

One of the reasons such a warning would exist is to prevent issues like the one you're experiencing.

---

Your version causes a segfault because you interpret the `uint8_t` value `buffer[0]` (likely either `0` or `80`, depending on endianness) as a pointer. This is likely to be an invalid pointer on personal computers, and dereferencing it causes a segfault on your platform.